# Can I install different language packages for the command line program "info"?

Tags: installation, package-management, language-support, command-line, info

I'd like to install info pages for the command line program in spanish so it will take less time for me to understand and assimilate.

Well, it may sound quite dumb, but the problem I'm having trying to get some information about this is that the word `info` is everywhere, so I don't actualy know if these language packs have a specific more technical name.

So is there a way to install different language packages for `info`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "info" documentation is part of the package with the binary, e.g. the wget package provides /usr/share/info/wget.info.gz and so on. And I don't see any language structure in /usr/share/info, so I guess there is no support for non-english languages.

"info" is really pretty unsearchable, try "texinfo" or "GNU info" instead.